# Struct with abstract-type field or with concrete-type Union in Julia?

Tags: performance, struct, julia, union-types, abstract-type

I have two concrete types called `CreationOperator` and `AnnihilationOperator` and I want to define a new concrete type that represents a string of operators and a real coefficient that multiplies it.

I found natural to define an abstract type `FermionicOperator`, from which both `CreationOperator` and `AnnihilationOperator` inherit, i.e.

```
abstract type FermionicOperator end

struct CreationOperator <: FermionicOperator
  ...
end

struct AnnihilationOperator <: FermionicOperator
  ...
end
```

because I can define many functions with signatures of the type `function(op1::FermionicOperator, op2::FermionicOperator) = ...`, such as arithmetic operations (I am building an algebra system, so I have to define operations such as `*`, `+`, etc. on the operators).
Then I would go on and define a concrete type `OperatorString`

```
struct OperatorString
  coef::Float64
  ops::Vector{FermionicOperator}
end
```

However, according to the Julia manual, I believe that `OperatorString` is not ideal for performance, because the compiler does not know anything about `FermionicOperator` and thus functions involving `OperatorString` will be inefficient (and I will have many functions manipulating strings of operators).

I found the following solution, however I am not sure about its implication and if it really makes a difference.
Instead of defining `FermionicOperator` as an abstract type, I define it is as the `Union` of `CreationOperator` and `AnnihilationOperator`, i.e.

```
struct CreationOperator
  ...
end

struct AnnihilationOperator
  ...
end

FermionicOperator = Union{CreationOperator,AnnihilationOperator}
```

This would still allow functions of the form `function(op1::FermionicOperator, op2::FermionicOperator) = ...`, but at the same time, to my understanding, `Union{CreationOperator,AnnihilationOperator}` is a concrete type, such that `OperatorString` is well-defined and the compilers can optimize things if it's the case.

I am particularly in doubt because I also considered to use the built-in `Expr` struct to define my string of operators (actually it would be more general), whose field `args` is a vector with abstract-type elements: very similar to my first design attempt.  However, while implementing arithmetic operations on `Expr` I had the feeling I was doing something "wrong" and I was better off defining my own types.

Comment: > `Union{CreationOperator,AnnihilationOperator}` is a concrete type. Unfortunately, no. You can use `isconcretetype` to check. I think https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/union-splitting will help you in some degree.

Comment: Indeed union-splitting is what I was thinking the compiler was able to do with unions. Actually, I don't care that much if they are not concrete-type as long as the resulting functions can be optimized.

Answer (score 4):

If your `ops` field is a vector that, in any given instance, is either all `CreationOperators` or all `AnnihilationOperators`, then the recommended solution is to use a parameterized struct.

```
abstract type FermionicOperator end

struct CreationOperator <: FermionicOperator
    ...
end

struct AnnihilationOperator <: FermionicOperator
    ...
end

struct OperatorString{T<:FermionicOperator}
  coef::Float64
  ops::Vector{T}

  function OperatorString(coef::Float64, ops::Vector{T}) where {T<:FermionicOperator}
      return new{T}(coef, ops)
  end
end
```

If your `ops` field is a vector that, in any given instance, may be a mixture of  `CreationOperators` and `AnnihilationOperators`, then you can use a Union. Because the union is small (2 types), your code will remain performant.

```
struct CreationOperator
    value::Int
end

struct AnnihilationOperator
    value::Int
end

const Fermionic = Union{CreationOperator, AnnihilationOperator}

struct OperatorString
  coef::Float64
  ops::Vector{Fermionic}

  function OperatorString(coef::Float64, ops::Vector{Fermionic})
      return new(coef, ops)
  end
end
```

Although not shown, even with the `Union` approach, you may want to use the abstract type also -- just for future simplicity and flexibility in function dispatch. It is helpful in developing robust multidispatch-driven logic.

Comment: It is the second situation. what do you mean to use also the abstract type? To have a `const Operator = Union{CreationOperator, AnnihilationOperator}' as well as `abstract type FermionicOperator end` to use in the method signature for dispatch?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I meant.